# How do I get only unique values from CSV file array

Tags: php, html, arrays, sorting, csv

I am building a small application that does some simple reporting based on CSV files, the CSV files are in the following format:

```
DATE+TIME,CLIENTNAME1,HAS REQUEST BLABLA1,UNIQUE ID
DATE+TIME,CLIENTNAME2,HAS REQUEST BLABLA2,UNIQUE ID
DATE+TIME,CLIENTNAME1,HAS REQUEST BLABLA1,UNIQUE ID
DATE+TIME,CLIENTNAME2,HAS REQUEST BLABLA2,UNIQUE ID
```

Now I am processing this using the following function:

```
function GetClientNames(){
    $file = "backend/AllAlarms.csv";
    $lines = file($file);
    arsort($lines);

    foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    $line_as_array = explode(",", $line);
        echo '<li><a href="#"><i class="icon-pencil"></i>' . $line_as_array[1] . '</a></li>';

    }
}
```

I am trying to retrieve only the Clientname values, but I only want the unique values.

I have tried to create several different manners of approaching this, I understand I need to use the unique_array function, but I have no clue on exactly how to use this function.

I've tried this:

```
function GetClientNames(){
    $file = "backend/AllAlarms.csv";
    $lines = file($file);
    arsort($lines);

    foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
        $line_as_array = explode(",", $line);
        $line_as_array[1] = unique_array($line_as_array[1]);
        echo '<li><a href="#"><i class="icon-pencil"></i>' . $line_as_array[1] . '</a></li>';
    }
}
```

But this gives me a very very dirty result with 100's of spaces instead of the correct data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend you to use the [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) function when reading in csv files. In the wild csv files can be quite complicated handle by naive explode() approach:

```
// this array will hold the results
$unique_ids = array();
// open the csv file for reading
$fd = fopen('t.csv', 'r');

// read the rows of the csv file, every row returned as an array
while ($row = fgetcsv($fd)) {
    // change the 3 to the column you want
    // using the keys of arrays to make final values unique since php
    // arrays cant contain duplicate keys
    $unique_ids[$row[3]] = true;
}

var_dump(array_keys($unique_ids));
```

You can also collect values and use [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) on them later. You probably want to split the *"reading in"* and the *"writing out"* part of your code too.

Comment: Thank you, this answer worked quite nicely :) Now I need to split some data still but that is a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `array_unique()`

Docs:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php